# C++ remove_if removes all following elements

Tags: c++, vector, lambda, iterator, sfml

I am trying to create a little game with c++ and SFML2 and I am stuck on this problem when I try to erase enemies objects.

I have a vector of "zombies" of type "Mover" and when I try to erase a specific zombie from the vector with this lambda function:

```
zombies.erase(remove_if(zombies.begin(), zombies.end(), [](Mover& m) {return m.isDead(); }), zombies.end());
```

it instead erase all following elements of the vector (if I have a 10 elements vector and I try to erase the 8th element it will erase elements num 8, 9 and 10).

I am still studying the language so it is probably a very dumb mistake but I have been looking for solutions for a long time now and I haven't found anything and the sample codes about lambdas and remove_if function look the same as mine to me.

Thank you for any help

-----EDIT-----

This is the isDead function:

```
bool Mover::isDead() { return hp.isEmpty(); }
```

which checks whether hp is less or equal to 0.

When I add new zombies this is what happens:

```
vector<Mover> zombies;

Mover z;

z.init(Vector2f(100, 100), Animator(120, Vector2f(512, 896), Vector2f(128, 128), texManager.get("zombie"), Vector2i(8, 1)));
z.setMaxSpeed(0.08);
z.setAngularVelocity(0.3);

for (int k = 0; k < 20; k++)
{
    z.setPosition(z.getPosition().x + 10, z.getPosition().y + 10);
    z.randomAnimation();
    zombies.push_back(z);
}
```

May the problem be here? Maybe I am doing something wrong with the init (code below) but I am not sure as this kind of initialisation is working for other kind of entities I have (such es projectiles).

```
void Mover::init(Vector2f _position, Animator _animator)
{
    setPosition(_position);
    animator = _animator;
    size = animator.getSize();
    rect.setSize(size);
    tex = animator.getTexture();
    sprite.setTexture(*tex);
    hp.init(15);
}
```

-----EDIT-----

Just added the copy constructor:

► Mover

Declaration

```
Mover(const Mover& other);
```

Definition

```
Mover::Mover(const Mover& other) : Entity(other)
{
    velocity = other.velocity;
    acceleration = other.acceleration;
    maxSpeed = other.maxSpeed;
    maxForce = other.maxForce;
    animator = other.animator;
    aVelocity = other.aVelocity;
    speedModifier = other.speedModifier;
    hp = other.hp;
}
```

► Entity

Declaration

```
Entity(const Entity& other);
```

Definition

```
Entity::Entity(const Entity& other) : Transformable(other), Drawable(other)
{
    size = other.size;
    rect = other.rect;
    tex = other.tex;
    sprite = other.sprite;
}
```

Same problem

Comment: This snippet looks okay, maybe show the `Mover` type

Comment: You really need to show a little more code than that.

Comment: Did you write copy (and/or move) constructor for `Mover` yourself? If so, what does it look like?

Comment: `operator=` is the assignment operator, not the copy constructor

Comment: I don't have copy or move constructor then. Should I write it? (I'm doing that anyway, I just want to know if my problem could be related to that)

Comment: @chtorr113: The Rule of Zero states that unless your class is very unusual, you should never have to write a Copy Constructor, Move Constructor, Assignment Operator or Destructor. And your case is not unusual, so don't write any of those :) Also, if you wish to get this question re-opened, you need to provide a MCVE (see link above). This requires you to distill the issue to a self-contained example, that is small enough to be posted here. In the process, you will probably uncover the bug and not need to ask ^^

Answer (score 2):

Using psychic debugging, your `Mover` type fails to properly move the state that `isDead` queries.